# Adding a Design time Panel to a TabPage at run time

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, panel

I wish to have a Panel with the controls on it at design time but I want to add this panel to a desired tabPage of my TabControl at run time.

I wrote something like this, did not work : the panel does not show up in the tab page.
please help me.

```
panel2.Parent = tabGuy.TabPages[0];
tabGuy.SuspendLayout();
tabGuy.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(panel2);
tabGuy.ResumeLayout();
panel2.Show();
```

Comment: At design time you don't need to write your code to add tabpage simply drag-and-drop panel to the tabpage in VisualEditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set the coordinates of the Panel as well, or (better) `panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

And you don't have to set the .Parent or call the .Show()