# Adding the same Panel to multiple TabPages

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950321/adding-a-design-time-panel-to-a-tabpage-at-run-time) I could add a design time panel to a tab page at run time and my code looks like this and it works Ok.

```
        tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
        tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(panel1);
        tabControl1.ResumeLayout();
```

but now I need to do something like this:

```
    tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
    tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(panel1);
    tabControl1.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(panel1);
    tabControl1.TabPages[2].Controls.Add(panel1);
    tabControl1.ResumeLayout();
```

which just at run-time I can know how many of these Tabpages I will need. but now for testing I am assuming I will have three tabPages

**the Problem** is that the panel only gets added to the **Last** tabPage,
How can I fix this? I want it get added to all of the tab pages
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. A control can have only one parent at a time. Luckily, only one tab page is visible at a time, so I guess you could move the panel between the pages as they are displayed? On the other hand, if the panel is to be located in the same place for all pages, perhaps it should not be placed *inside* the tab control, but rather *on top* of it?

Comment: Ok Thanks, so I guess I should do this: Parent of Panel should be TabPage[0] AT FIRST because the at least I will have one page and th user will see it at first. ...but on the event of TabPageChange I should change the Parent of that Panel to be TabPage[currentTabIndex] 
Is that Ok?

Comment: @BDotA: I *think* that should work. I would give it a shot and see how it works out.

Comment: @FredrikMörk Excellent concept - I was able to apply this to my vb.net project: One thing that I found might need clarifying is that when you say "on top of the control" I found it easier to position my panel so most of it overlapped on top of the tab control, then I resized the panel to fit within the bounds of the tab. My initial try was to litterally place the panel on top of (and inside of) the tab - it needs to be placed outside of the tab for this to work.